# (node:5540) Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following code:

```
function handleError(res, statusCode) {
  statusCode = statusCode || 500;
  return function(err) {
    res.status(statusCode).send(err);
  };
}

function respondWithResult(res, statusCode) {
  statusCode = statusCode || 200;
  return function(entity) {
    if (entity) {
      res.status(statusCode).json(entity);
    }
  };
}


// Creates a new Store in the DB
export function create(req, res) {
  // create user
  let user = req.body.user;
  let store = req.body.store;

  auth.hash(user.password)
    .then(hash => {
      user.password = hash;
      // Create user, then create store, attach store object id to user, and attach user object id to store
      User.create(user)
      .then(userRes => {
        store.owner    = userRes._id;
        store.memebers = [];
        store.memebers.push(store.owner);

        Store.create(store)
        .then(storeRes => {
          return respondWithResult(res, 201);
        })
        .catch(err => handleError(err));
      })
      .catch(err => handleError(err));
    })
    .catch(err => handleError(err));
}
```

prints the error mentioned in the title, "(node:5540) Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it". I have tried changing and tweaking the code but the error still persists.

Comment: did you tried to `return auth.hash` ?

Comment: Tried it just now, but sadly it still produced the same error.

Comment: Plenty of unreturned promises there actually. It's just a warning but it can be an error.

Comment: There's also no need to do the three catches, you can just leave it at the end (but you'll have to return the promises)

Comment: Ok thans i'll remove all of the catches and just leave one. But how do i solve the issue of unreturned promises. i only recently started messing around with promises so forgive me if i missed anything obvious.

Comment: Well, you'd need to return all the promises. That means `return User.create(..)`, `return Store.create(..)` and `return auth.hash(..)`

Comment: Thanks this resolved my issue :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is because your code is creating promises inside of `.then()` handlers, but not returning them from those handlers.

Change:

```
User.create(user)
```

to:

```
return User.create(user)
```

And, change:

```
Store.create(store)
```

to

```
return Store.create(store)
```

When you don't return these promises that are created inside `.then()` handlers, they become separate, independent promise chains and are not linked to the previous promise chain.  This is usually a programming mistake which is why Bluebird makes it a warning.

When you return them, then they add to the promise chain and thus the parent promise waits for their completion before continuing on with the chain.

---

I'd also suggest you probably want to change:

```
auth.hash(user.password)
```

to:

```
return auth.hash(user.password)
```

So that the caller of `create()` can tell when everything is done.

---

And, you only need one `.catch()` handler at the highest level.  Rejected promises propagate up to the top level for you automatically (one of the things that makes error handling when using promises easier).

Answer (score -1):

This is a warning message when you don't return to a request. Of course this seems just another warning but when you work on a big application this becomes a very big headache because this will lead to a memory leak and wont release the memory until you restart your app or might crush your server.

you also need to return for else statments:

```
function respondWithResult(res, statusCode) {
  statusCode = statusCode || 200;
  return function(entity) {
    if (entity) {
      res.status(statusCode).json(entity);
    }else{ 
      //you should write an else statement also
      //maybe something like this
       res.status(statusCode).send(err);        
    }
  };
}
```

Return to your request in every case.

Comment: May i ask why i got -1 ?

Comment: Because your answer has nothing at all to do with the question that is asked.

Comment: you basically did the same thing `User.create(user)User.create(user)` to `return User.create(user)` returning to a request

Comment: I addressed the exact two lines in the OP's code that were causing this warning and explained why this warning exists.  You did neither.  This is not a generic issue with returning from a function - it's a specific issue about returning promises from within `.then()` handlers.